# How to make input required if specific options are selected in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm struggling with making a input field required only if specific options are selected in a `<select>` list.

For example:

```
<select id="model">
    <option value="model1">Model 1</option>
    <option value="model2">Model 2</option>
    <option value="model3">Model 3</option>
    <option value="model4">Model 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="extra">
```

The input `extra` gets required if Model 2 or 3 is selected.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by _making an input required_? Do you have a validation code? If so, check the value of `model` dropdown before validating.

Comment: Yes I mean that I need the form to be validated and make the input field required.

Comment: Try to use jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: There are two ways to make your input field "required". One is to even have it appear on the page. The other is to verify there is a value inside the field. See my example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully working example to demonstrate how to use jQuery to solve both cases. Note that you must include the reference to the jQuery library as I have done in the head tags. You also might move the javascript/jQuery into a separate file and simply include it by reference.

[Live example (jsFiddle) here](http://jsfiddle.net/AGy6k/2/)

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
//alert('Document is ready');
                $('#model').change(function() {
                    var sel = $(this).val();
                    if (sel == 'model2' || sel == 'model3') $('input[name=extra]').show();
                });

                $('input[name=btn_submit]').click(function() {
                    var sel = $('#model').val();
                    if (sel == 'model2' || sel == 'model3') {
                        if ($('input[name=extra]').val() == '') {
                            alert('Please complete all fields');
                            return false; //prevent submit from submitting
                        }else{
                            alert('Your entry was submitted');
                        }
                    }else{
                        //Model is NOT 2 or 3 so don't check
                        alert('Your entry was submitted without checking input field value.');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <select id="model">
        <option value="model1">Model 1</option>
        <option value="model2">Model 2</option>
        <option value="model3">Model 3</option>
        <option value="model4">Model 4</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="extra" style="display:none">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit It">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you add this 
if (sel == 'model1' || sel == 'model4') $('input[name=extra]').hide();
to hide the input if the user choose by error to click 2 and 3 ^^

Answer (score 0):

Well you can only do so much with javascript client-side. Ultimately you will have to enforce this on the server. To do this client-side without relying on browser specific implementations or HTML5, you will need to manually check the values you want to be requires with an `onsubmit()` event handler.

`<form onsubmit="return validateFormData(this)">`

Also be sure to give your select element a name for ease of use:

`<select id="model" name="model"></select>`

Then in your javascript:

```
function validateFormData(oForm) {
    //Let's say that a value of 'model3' makes 'extra' required
    if(oForm.model.value=='model3') {
        if(oForm.extra.value=='') {
            //returning false will prevent the form from submitting
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a required class when a certain option is selected. Then on submit check the required elements to make sure something it's not empty

```
$('#model').change(function () {
    // check if it's model2 or model3
    var isRequired = /model2|model3/i.test(this.value);
    $('input[name=extra]').toggleClass('required',isRequired);    
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    // get all empty required fields
    var reqEmpty = $('.required').filter(function(){
       return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    });
    // if any empty required fields are found - do something
    if(reqEmpty.length){
        alert('empty required field');
        return false;
    }
});
```

the red border in the fiddle is just to show you when the required class has been added.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/27yvR/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to set the `required` *property*:

```
$('#model').change(function(){
    var index = this.selectedIndex;
    $('input[name="extra"]').prop('required', function(){
        return index == 1 || index == 2;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gRMb5/).